# How should a Python virtual environment be created so that it can be archived in a repository for use by multiple people?

Tags: python, svn, virtualenv, tar

I've got a Python virtual environment that is intended to provide an environment for many people.

- It is to be stored in SVN in order to ensure that the environment is "frozen" for various releases.
- I have attempted to make it "dynamic" in the sense that the environment activation script is made to not contain a hardcoded path and I have attempted to make it relocatable because it is to be used by many people at many different directories.
- I have *archived* the environment because storing it as a directory in the repository would mean that updates to the environment would result in SVN change summaries that would be almost unreadable.
- In have split the archive across multiple files in order to respect SVN file size restrictions.

Is this approach robust? Are there likely to be problems when multiple people use it at multiple directories? Is archiving in the way I am doing it a good idea? Are there better approaches to any of the ideas I've expressed?

The specific procedure I'm using is something like the following:

```
ssh "${USER}"@sern.ch
setupSALTAEnvironment

echo "create Python virtual environment"
virtual_environment_name="virtual_environment"
virtualenv "${virtual_environment_name}"

echo "make activation dynamic"
activate_filename="virtual_environment/bin/activate"
temporary_filename="/tmp/"$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ" --utc)""
cat > "${temporary_filename}" << "EOF"
directory_bin="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
directory_env="$(dirname "${directory_bin}")"
VIRTUAL_ENV="${directory_env}"
EOF
sed -i "/^VIRTUAL_ENV.*/ {
   r ${temporary_filename}
   d
}" "${activate_filename}"
rm "${temporary_filename}"

echo "activate Python virtual environment"
source "${virtual_environment_name}"/bin/activate

IFS= read -d '' text << "EOF"
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")
EOF
echo "${text}" > "${virtual_environment_name}"/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py

echo "install software in Python virtual environment"
pip install docopt
pip install dataset
pip install numpy
pip install matplotlib
pip install pyfiglet
pip install datavision
pip install nodemaster
pip install propyte
pip install git+https://github.com/wdbm/pyprel.git
pip install git+https://github.com/wdbm/pyrecon.git
pip install shijian
pip install technicolor
#pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
#pip install git+git://github.com/google/skflow.git

echo "make Python virtual environment relocatable"
virtualenv --relocatable virtual_environment

echo "archive Python virtual environment with respect to SVN limitations"
tar -czf - virtual_environment/ | split --bytes=50MB - virtual_environment.tgz.
rm -rf virtual_environment
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure of what you are trying to do, but why don't you just track the above file with svn and tell people to execute the script to get the environment?

Comment: As far as I know, `virtualenv` team never managed to make environments truly portable.

Comment: Are you asking because you are afraid of version shear when someone else tries to create a similar virtualenv later using a script?

Comment: You dont need to activate your environment, thats a rookie mistake i see time and time again. Reference it, `$virtual_environment_name/bin/pip install ... ` this saves you a lot of trouble

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you aren't using a requirements file for pip? That would make your job much easier and also ensure a particular **version** of each  dependency.

Comment: @Altoyr Thanks for the comment. Managing the archive files on SVN isn't much of a problem -- it's just a matter of updating big binary files. I'm more asking about whether my approach to creating the virtual environment is sensible and likely to be robust enough for it to work reliably for other people working at other directories.

Comment: @Lav As far as I can see, you're right. As shown above, I have attempted to change the activation script so that it at least doesn't have its default hardcoded path, making it a bit more dynamic and relocatable. Does my approach seem sensible? Am I missing anything?

Comment: @zxq9 Forgive me, I'm not familiar with the term "version shear". I'm not particularly concerned about managing the archived virtual environment in SVN; I'm more concerned with making the environment sufficiently robust and portable that it can be used by multiple people at multiple directories.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Thanks for the suggestion. I want to look into this approach. The virtual environment is designed to make the user's environment appropriate for a suite of scripts that are not stored in the environment itself (they are tracked simply in SVN). I want others to be able to check out the repository and then use scripts in the repository that require the dependencies provided by the virtual environment. Would your approach be suitable for such a scenario?

Comment: @Suever Thanks for your suggestion. That is a very good idea. I'll look into implementing it.

Comment: @d3pd yes as long as the permissions allow for it.. I normally run everything under a very limited user `www-data`

Comment: @d3pd Yea I think your best option here rather than trying to distribute a complete virtualenv would be to just write a script to setup a virtualenv on the users computer (as you've basically done here) and with that provide a requirements file that is in version control. Then you have a specific version of all packages used and a reproducible way to build the environment. Also this would work on any OS/architecture.